# jquery add class to background-image

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I want to use animate.css to animate the background image of a div (e.g. applying a pulse effect). I have to add the desired animation classes to any element which I want to animate in the following format:

```
<img class="animated infinite pulse">
```

now my question is that how is it possible to add these classes to a background image in a div? I tried to select the background-image using jquery and add classes to it but got errors:

```
var psd = $('#mydiv').css('background-image');
$(psd).addClass("animated infinite pulse");
```

or another code:

```
$('#mydiv').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("background-image"); 
}).addClass('animated infinite pulse');
```

The last code adds the animation classes to the whole div and makes the whole div animated. Please help with this issue.

Comment: you want to add class property to background image?

Comment: yes, I am trying to control only the background image in a div and not all the content of the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `addClass()` to element with `background-image` not `css` property.

```js
var psd = $('#mydiv'); // This has background image already
$(psd).addClass("animated infinite pulse");
```

```css
#mydiv {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg');
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" />
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Or fixed `background-image`:

```js
var psd = $('#mydiv'); // This has background image already
$(psd).addClass("animated infinite pulse");
```

```css
#mydiv {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/HDRI_Sample_Scene_Balls_%28JPEG-HDR%29.jpg');
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}

#parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css" />
<div id="parent">
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pedram for the answer. It looks like the only possible solution especially the fixed background image example. The problem is that as I am using a page builder in Joomla, I have not much control over how my divs are structured and can not create a blank div containing only a background-image, therefore, #mydiv has also my other elements in it like buttons and texts and all of them get animated. Thank you for taking time to create these examples.